# What are the tenses in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-tense, future, sequence-of-tenses

I'd like to break this sentence down to its components and their tenses, but I'm struggling. How would you explain it?

**“I think we thought it would be easier”**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. *Think* is inflected into the present tense here.
2. *Thought* is inflected into the past tense here.
3. There are no other tenses here nor anywhere else in the entire English language.

And that *would* part has no tense because it's a modal, but it's the backshifted version of *will*. Sometimes people call that sort of thing a future-in-past construction, but it's only a construction not an inflected morphological tense.

Comment: Dunno -- modals always make me tense.